# Is the least square estimator unique?

Tags: regression, linear-model, least-squares

Given $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ and $y\in \mathbb R^n$, the least square coefficients are: $\hat{\beta} = \text{argmin} \| X\beta - y\|^2_2$.

Is $\hat{\beta}$ unique in the case $\text{rank}(X)=p$?

Comment: Yes, providing that $n \ge p$. The key is that $\beta$ is unique if the columns of $X$ are linearly independent, which $rank(X) = p$ combined with $n \ge p$ ensures.

Comment: can you write a proof ?

Comment: I could, but I leave that to you as an exercise.

Comment: There's a algebraic-geometric proof if you know the theory of vector spaces. Are you familiar with vector spaces ?

Comment: Also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194460

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume $\text{rank}(X) = p$ and $n \geq p$ (in fact $\text{rank}(X) = p$ implies that $n \geq p$), the least square estimator has an explicit expression:
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty,$$
in which $X^TX$ is non-singular. Since the inverse is unique, $\hat{\beta}$ is unique.

So probably the only difficult part is to show that $X^TX$ is non-singular provided $\text{rank}(X) = p$. There are multiple ways to show that, perhaps the easiest way is to use
$$\text{rank}(X^TX) = \text{rank}(X) \tag{$*$}$$
for any real matrix $X$, also note that $X^TX$ is a $p \times p$ matrix, thus $X^TX$ has to be non-singular. Let me know if you need a proof for $(*)$.