# How cost function for simple linear regression behaves under different settings with batch gradient descent?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, saddlepoint-approximation

In the linear regression problem, using a simple linear model with 1 variable & with 2 model parameters, performing batch Gradient Descent(GD) & assuming I am using Mean Square error as my cost function, will ensure that we will get only 1 local minimum which is global minimum!. So,**the GD will always converge keeping the learning rate to neither too small or too large!**

[image: cost function surface]

1. But if we increase the number of model parameters lets say to 5 what will happen in the above setting?
2. Also, when we just keep simple linear model and make the feature in higher order polynomial or take sin/ cos of the feature! what will happen?
3. In the above case if we increase the number of variables, with high order polynomials or taking sin, then what will happen?

Could anyone help me understand these 3 serious, if you could add 3-D plots of these functions or even contour plots(additionally, if you could argue simultaneous how the behavior of batch gradient descent will change in all 3 scenarios), it will really help to get a clear understanding of each of these scenarios!

***NOTE: I asked for plots just for an understanding of these 3 scenarios with 2 parameters & later an explanation(connecting intuition) for >3.***

Comment: Generally speaking, as the error surface becomes increasingly complex the number of minima increases such that the ere are many local minima. In your 3D surface plot, there is a single local minimum which is also the global minimum - with increasing model complexity this will not be the case.

Comment: thanks, @JamesPhillips, I am aware of this fact but I am looking for a deep dive into each aspect of the model, features, & cost function complexity and GD's effect in each case.

Comment: If the local minimum in your plot is the single global minimum, starting parameters are not so important because there is only one minimum for the algorithm to converge to. However if there is more than one local minimum, as the number of minima increase the starting parameters and learning rate become increasingly important.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, got it!, I can understand how the learning rate would be important, but how the starting parameter(what that start means in 2 parameter space?) will be important? Also, just correct me if I am wrong, assuming I am using MSE as a loss function for linear regression problem, so the curved surface is due to nature of MSE, it's squared so parabola? that means if there are 2 model parameters(MP), I have 1 valley, if 3 MP, then 2 valleys, so and so forth, so as the parameter grows there will be and & more valleys?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, also, could you comment on my 2nd question, if we change the squared error function(MSE) to absolute error function(MAE) or some cubic function, how it will affect the cost calculation & curve surface?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, Any coments on 3rd question, keeping the MSE as loss function, if we apply transformations on features, such as taking squares of them, or doing feature crosses or applying sin() which basically makes fitting a curve instead of line, then in my opinion , it won't effect the number of valleys in cost function's space, as the cost function is a function of just model parameters and trying to come up with a minimum point in cost function space which corresponds to a best fit(line/ complex curve) in hypothesis a.k.a model space?  any quesiton or comment?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking under what conditions the quadratic cost function is strictly convex. Is that your question, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @Sycorax, thanks for replying, but I am not enough well-versed to communicate in mathematical language! could you write your suggestion in a little simpler words?  I don't know under what condition a quadratic curve might be non-convex, I assumed that quadratic curves are always convex, I could be completely wrong, please correct me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is regression line (for a simple "Y given X" regression, no interaction etc) always unique?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194460/is-regression-line-for-a-simple-y-given-x-regression-no-interaction-etc-alw)

Comment: I was discussing *error space*, not the fitted function itself.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, yes, I use error space & cost function space interchangeably, so my comment still validates! any suggestions on that. Also, I relate minima in error space to a best-fit line/curve in hypothesis space for my understanding!

Comment: How do you propose making "3-D plots" when more than two parameters have been introduced into the model, which is the case in each of your three situations?

Comment: @whuber, that's true, I can correct my words, but I was expecting a visual understanding with <3 M. Parameters using 3D or contour plots and with >3 some intuition following along the visual. Any clear explanation would also work! :)

Comment: Your plot does a fine job: all 2D cross-sections in higher dimensions will look (qualitatively) the same. That's because all the loss functions can be expressed as sums of squares (an example of the "spectral theorem" of linear algebra).

Comment: @whuber, so do you mean to say all 3 points listed above in MSE setting will behave the same?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "behave the same" or "will happen," but I do know--because you are minimizing a sum of squares in every case--that any portrayal of the objective function is going to look qualitatively just like your plot.

Comment: [It is impossible to construct an algorithm that will find a global minimum for an arbitrary function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlobalMinimum.html). However, using defined ranges, there are routines for finding  [global minima](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html). Moreover, without also characterizing what the appropriate models are, the appropriate data transformations, and the appropriate norm(s) for minimization, there is no correct regression procedure.