# How to prove the cost function of a neural network with only linear activation functions is convex？

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is the cost function of a neural network with only linear activation functions a convex function with respect to its parameters? If it is, how to prove it?

Comment: Linear functions are closed under composition; linear regression is convex under some assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm opening up the statement made in the comments.

A neural network with linear activation and many layers is equivalent to a neural network with one layer. For example:

$$W_2(W_1x+b_1)+b_2=Wx+b$$

So, in the end, your equation is $Wx+b=y$, i.e. just a linear regression. The cost function is already convex, because it is norm-squared of an affine function. Also, more strongly, the problem is a convex [*problem*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194460/is-regression-line-for-a-simple-y-given-x-regression-no-interaction-etc-alw).